# Constraint error with private part, arrays and pointers

Tags: arrays, pointers, constraints, ada

I am trying to do a typical Get procedure with this features:

Header:

```
procedure Get (M:Map; Key: in Key_Type; Value: out Value_Type; Success: out Boolean) is
```

private part:

```
type Cell is record
    Key: Key_Type;
    Value: Value_Type;
    Full:Boolean:= False;
end record

type Cell_Array is array (1..50) of Cell;
type Cell_Array_A is access Cell_Array;

type Map is record   
    P_Array: Cell_Array_A;
    Length:Natural=0;
    Indice:Natural;
end record
```

My first condition on my Get procedure has the following aspect:

```
for k in 1..NumClien loop
    if M.P_Array(k).Key = Key then 
...
```

But when I try to execute it, it always gives me the following error:
Lower_Layer.Inet(Receiver_Task): Unexpected exception raised CONSTRAINT_ERROR

How can I solve it?
PS: Header of the Get procedure and private part are mandatory...

Thank you!

Comment: Wild guess: `M.P_Array = null`

Comment: What is `NumClien`?

Comment: As Jeffrey has pointed out, using an access type in this implementation (as you say you are forced to do) is very poor Ada practice. It leads to all sorts of problems; from failure to allocate the P_Array, through failing to deal properly with copies of Maps, to failing to deallocate the contents when finished with. There are of course times when using access types is unavoidable; this isn’t one of them

Answer (score 3):

if you eliminate the unnecessary use of access types, your problem will go away:

```
type Map is record
   List : Cell_Array;
   ...
end record;
```

Access types are needed so rarely in well designed Ada that I'm tempted to say "never".